Orthogonal Complement of linear subspace
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $a := (a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in k^n$ be a vector such that $a_i \neq 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. Let $W$ be the linear subspace of $k^n$ spanned by $a$. Let $W^{\perp}$ be the orthogonal complement of $W$, i.e.,
$ 
W^{\perp} := \{ u = (u_1, \ldots, u_n) \in k^n \mid u \cdot v = u_1 v_1 + \ldots + u_n v_n = 0, \text{ for all } v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n) \in W \}. 
$
My question is, how can we show that there exists a vector $b = (b_1, \ldots, b_n) \in W^{\perp}$ such that $b_i \neq 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$? This problem is straightforward if $n$ is even. However, if $n$ is odd, it requires some new ideas.

Hint: Because $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n}$ are all nonzero elements of a field of characteristic zero, there exists $n-1$ scalars from this list such that their sum is nonzero (proved by contradiction). From this, can you give such a vector $b$?

Hi thanks @DuongNgo for comment. I admit there exists $n-1$ scalars such that their sum is nonzero. However, it is not clear for me to construct such $b$

You should construct $b$ by setting $b_1 = b_2 = ... = b_{n-1} = 1$ and then try to find a suitable (nonzero) value for $b_n$.

thanks a lot, I get the construction

Let $c_2, \ldots, c_n$ be any set of nonzeros each in $k$. Then as all of the $a_i$s are nonzero, it follows that at least one of
$\sum_{i=2}^n a_ic_i$ and $2a_2c_2 + \sum_{i=3}^n a_ic_i$ is not $0$ [indeed the latter differs from the former by an additive $a_2c_2$ which is not $0$ as neither $a_2$ nor $c_2$ is $0$ and $k$ is a field of characteristic $\not =$ $2$].

If on the one hand $\sum_{i=2}^n a_ic_i$ is nonzero [must be true if $n$ is $2$ by the way]: Then
let $b$ be the vector in $k^n$ where the 1st coordinate $b_1$ of $b$ satisfies
$b_1 = -\frac{\sum_{i=2}a_ic_i}{a_1}$, and for the remaining coordinates $b_2, \ldots, b_n$ of $b$ satisfy $b_i=c_i$ for all $i =2,\ldots, n$.  Note that $b_1$ is nonzero.

If on the other hand $\sum_{i=2}^n a_ic_i$ is zero: Then as noted above, $2a_2c_2 + \sum_{i=3}^n a_ic_i$ is not $0$. So then let $b$ be the vector where the first coordinate $b_1$ of $b$ satisfies
$b_1 = -\frac{2a_2c_2 +\sum_{i=3}a_ic_i}{a_1}$, and the second coordinate $b_2$ of $b$ satisfies $b_2=2c_2$, and for the remaining coordinates $b_3, \ldots, b_n$ satisfy $b_i=c_i$ for all $i =3,\ldots, n$. Note that everything here is nonzero as well.


AN ASIDE: We used implicitly that $k$ is a field of characteristic $\not = 2$ by stating $a_2c_2 \not = 0 \implies 2a_2c_2 \not = 0$, all we really needed however is that $k$ has at least $2$ distinct nonzero elements, which characteristic $0$, and even characteristic $\not =2$, provides, and in fact any field on $3$ or more elements--even those of $3$ or more elements and still characteristic $2$, provides. [Indeed, let $c \not = 1$ be a nonzero element in $k$. Then  $a_2c_2 \not = 0 \implies ca_2c_2 \not = 0$...]
